# Check if a directory (symlink) still points to the same place

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I take care of a script that for each release copies out to a release-folder for example `release/version_0.0.2`. I also set a symlink to this version (the folder `release/version_0.0.2`) called `latest`. To run the script you have to be in the folder the script is in (bad design decision with relative paths).

My problem is the users of this script want almost all the time use the latest version. So they set `latest` to work directory and run the script there from. But when I release a new version they will automatic use the old one, so want the script (written in bash) to ask the user if he/she want to use this old one.

My ide was to check if the script is run from `latest`, but when I change the symlink the $PWD is change when I run the script but not in the shell.

Here is a example:

```
selnx183:~> cd latest/
selnx183:~/latest> echo $PWD
/home/ejohael/latest
selnx183:~/latest> ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
11082 pts/190  00:00:00 tcsh
32527 pts/190  00:00:00 ps
selnx183:~/latest> pwdx 11082
11082: /home/ejohael/release/version_0.0.2
selnx183:~/latest> ./test 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/ejohael/latest
/home/ejohael/latest
/home/ejohael/latest
/home/ejohael/release/version_0.0.2
~/latest

-------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/ejohael/latest
selnx183:~/latest> rm ~/latest
selnx183:~/latest> ln -s ~/release/version_0.0.3/ ~/latest
selnx183:~/latest> echo $PWD
/home/ejohael/latest
selnx183:~/latest> ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
11082 pts/190  00:00:00 tcsh
32727 pts/190  00:00:00 ps
selnx183:~/latest> pwdx 11082
11082: /home/ejohael/release/version_0.0.2
selnx183:~/latest> ./test 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/ejohael/release/version_0.0.2
/home/ejohael/release/version_0.0.2
/home/ejohael/release/version_0.0.2
/home/ejohael/release/version_0.0.2
~/release/version_0.0.2

-------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/ejohael/release/version_0.0.2
selnx183:~/latest>
```

The test look as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo `env` > log

echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------"

echo $PWD
echo `pwd`
echo `cd -L . ; pwd`
echo `cd -P . ; pwd`
echo `dirs`
echo $OLDPWD

echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------"

pushd `dirname -- $0` > /dev/null
echo `pwd -L`
popd > /dev/null
```

I do not want to force the user always use the latest version but I what to find out when the user think it uses the latest version and warn the user.

**Edit:** I want only get this if the user is running from a old latest, not when the user run a old version from release/version_x.x.x.

Comment: A script that asked me questions about installation would annoy me.  Think about providing an installer, perhaps?  Or fix it so that the user doesn't have to be in the directory (which would annoy me even more).  That way, the user is in control and can set things so that they use the version they want without discussion from the script trying to second guess their intent.  The installer can switch the 'latest' symlink to itself (if it doesn't find a more recent version already in place; think of reinstalling an old version).  Having the version-numbered locations is a _good_ feature.

Answer (score 1):

I would think about something like

```
[ $(stat -c%i .) != $(stat -L -c%i ../latest) ] && echo not in the latest directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand completely what the situation is, but do you know about the `readlink` command? `readlink latest` will print the name of the file/folder that `latest` points to. Your script would know what `latest` should point to; any deviation from that can trigger a warning to the user.